# Creating a custom React Native component which automatically wraps inner text substrings with another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the following component structure being rendered:

```xml
<Text>
 Hello <UsernameWrapper>@gaberocksall</UsernameWrapper>! Nice to meet you.
</Text>
```

I would like create a custom component which automatically places `@username`s into a `UsernameWrapper`, like this (and it should be rendered identically to the above snippet):

```xml
<AutoUsernameText>Hello @gaberocksall! Nice to meet you.</AutoUsernameText>
```

Or, even more generally, something along the lines of:

```xml
<MagicWrapper wrap={/@\w+/gi} wrapper={UsernameWrapper}>
  Hello @gaberocksall! Nice to meet you.
</MagicWrapper>
```

How would I go about creating the `MagicWrapper` component in React Native?

Comment: P.S. How do I get the syntax highlighting to be correct for `.tsx` files? I ended up using the `xml` format option with is about 90% correct for these examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could just create a new component where we pass the `username` as a prop. In my opinion that is the way to go in react-native. Here is a quick implementation.

```js
export const AutoUsernameText = (props) => {
   return (
       <Text>
         Hello <UsernameWrapper>@{props.name}</UsernameWrapper>! Nice to meet you.
       </Text>
   )
}
```

Then, we can just use it as follows.

```js
const SomeOtherScreen = () => {

   return (
       <AutoUsernameText name="gaberocksall" />
   )
}
```

Notice that this solution depends on how `UsernameWrapper` is actually implemented. Since I do not know that, I assume plain strings here.

If you really want to pass it as a child, e.g.

```js
<MagicWrapper>Hello @gaberocksal! Nice to meet you.</MagicWrapper>
```

then `AutoUsernameText` needs to parse its children and return the component you want instead. This is possible, although I do not see any good reason why one should do that. It opens many pitfalls that are not easy to avoid.

Nevertheless, we can achieve this as follows assuming that the child is a simple string using plain JS regular expressions.

```js
export const MagicWrapper = (props) => {
  // Notice that I do not guard here for potential errors ...
  // props.children could be anything ...
  const child = props.children
  const name = child.match(/@\S+?(?=!)/g)
  const content = child.split(name)

  return (
       <Text> 
         {content[0]}<UsernameWrapper>{name}</UsernameWrapper>{content[1]}
       </Text>
   )
}
```

Comment: The assumption here is that the text is freeform, entered by the user (think, rendering a mention in a stackoverflow comment). So I think I will go with something along the lines of the second example (but I'll add reasonable type checks) - I'll test this out and accept the answer if I can get it working - Thanks!

Comment: That sounds more like a TextInput where we just  parse words starting with @ and then wrap it into your desired component. I might be mistaken though. I hope that my answer helps you anyway! Do not hesitate to ask if you have further questions :)

Comment: I was able to get it working using a [slightly modified version](https://pastebin.com/r4rwAhWX) of your `MagicWrapper`, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to splitting specific Regex pattern like as username, url and etc, you are able to use **react-native-parsed-text** package. For example it's will help you changing color of the Regex pattern (also defining custom styles) or defining onPress function to doing some things. I hope it's be useful.
[react-native-parsed-text](https://github.com/taskrabbit/react-native-parsed-text) github page.